# Use Xcopy to move files and change file extension

Tags: xcopy

I am looking to move files and change their file ext.  Can I move .xlsx files from one location and then change the extension to text. Here is what I have done.  It moves just fine. How do I incorperate changing the extension.

```
xcopy  /# "\\XXX\R$\wtr\Departments\Operations\Metrics\Metrics-Production\BI 
Data Dump\*.xlsx" "X:\Data Files\Yield Summary Data"

  Thanks in Advance,
```

Comment: Were you able to test this with \\*.txt at the end? If successful accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this:

> xcopy  /Y
>   "\\Tom\R$\wtr\Departments\Operations\Metrics\Metrics-Production\BI 
>   Data Dump\*.xlsx" "G:\Data Files\Yield Summary Data\*.txt"

\*.txt at the end of your destination.